# Can fields within the state be changed using setState depending on user input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a form that will have three input fields and I want to change the state to what has been input. Instead of having to write three separate functions to handle all three inputs is there a way to set the state depending on the field the user has chosen to fill in?

Thanks in advance.

```
handleChange = e => {
        this.setState({
            //Can this be changed to target the right field in the state// : e.target.value
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
                    <input 
                        type="text"
                        value={this.state.name}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="county">County:</label>
                    <input 
                        type="text"
                        value={this.state.county}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="position">Position:</label>
                    <input 
                        type="text"
                        value={this.state.position}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                </div>
                <button>Submit Player</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: Adding the name to each input will do that

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code

```
handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
         [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
                <input 
                    type="text"
                    name="name"
                    value={this.state.name}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="county">County:</label>
                <input 
                    type="text"
                    name="county"
                    value={this.state.county}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="position">Position:</label>
                <input 
                    type="text"
                    name="position"
                    value={this.state.position}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
            </div>
            <button>Submit Player</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Please remove ...this.state in setState.

Comment: 1. setState just updates applied values and leaves others as they are, 2. setState is asynchron so you may discard other state changes, 3. If you depend on values of current state use this.setState((state) => ({foo: state.foo + 1})) to avoid discarding  changes (2.)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than relying on anything in the DOM to identify the elements you want to update - which is not exactly best practice for React, because it confuses where the source of truth of state and model lie - you should abstract the form away entirely into a data structure:

```
state = {
    formInputs: [
        {
            name: 'Name',
            type: 'text',
            value: '',
        },
        {
            name: 'Country',
            type: 'text',
            value: '',
        },
        {
            name: 'Position',
            type: 'text',
            value: '',
        },
    ]
};
handleChange = (evt, n) => {
    this.setState((state) => {
        const arr = state.formInputs.slice();
        arr[n] = {value: evt.target.value, ...arr[n]};
        return {formInputs: arr};
    });
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.formInputs.map((ea, i) => {
                return (
                    <div key={ea.name} >
                        <label htmlFor={ea.name}>{`${ea.name}:`}</label>
                        <input {...ea} onChange={(e) => {this.handleChange(e, i)}} />
                    </div>
                );
            })}
            <button>Submit Player</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Storing the data/inputs and their value in abstract component state -- and then using `Array.map()` to transform them into rendered UI -- is a very common and useful pattern in React.

Advantages:

- Source of truth for state, the data model, and how to render it is completely unambiguous and 100% under React's control
- Can add an arbitrary number of inputs and have them render dynamically
- One single update function that will handle updating an arbitrary data field's stored value
- Uses recommended [React "controlled component"](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) pattern

Comment: State changes depending on current state should use updaterFn. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: @JannikS. Not strictly necessary in most cases but best practice in general I suppose. Edited.

Comment: Was just writing comment to other answer about related issue but there it's not just a "best practise" thing :D That's why I wanted to mention it here, too.

Comment: There are different patterns in React, you have made this simple form overcomplicated. There are no dynamic input fields, why do you keep them on a map? It would be better focus on the question.

Comment: Hey, isn't it great that we have 1 answer that directly addresses the question and one that is giving a slightly different approach with some details to a related topic? Keep in mind that Andy wanted to generalise his code, which this answer does even further than he asked for. :)

Comment: Yeah @JannikS I agree with you up to some point and this answer works perfectly fine, but my point was there is no requirement to make this form with dynamic inputs.